# Rails associations query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At the moment, I have an association between a `User` and a `Pdform`. I want to find all of the `pdforms` associated with a `user` where the `user` has a `office` of 'BA'. How can I achieve this with `Rails`?

I attempted adding this in my `pdforms_controller`:

```
@user_approvals = Pdform.where(@user.office == 'BA')
```

But I get this error message:

> undefined method `office' for nil:NilClass

I am looking at the database right now and the `office` attribute associated with the user is set.

I am still getting the hang of rails so excuse me if this is the completely wrong way to create queries.

Comment: I don't use `ActiveRecord` much, but I believe it should be `Pdform.where(user: {office: 'BA'})`. If that doesn't work, try `user` pluralized and/or capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all `pdforms` that don't belong to concrete user, just those that belong to users whose `office == 'BA'`, you can do it like this:

```
@user_approvals = Pdform.joins(:user).where(users: { office: 'BA'})
```

I assume that you have

```
belongs_to :user
```

in your `Pdform` model.

Comment: That goes in the Pdform or the User model, Maksim?

Comment: @TrentonTyler `belongs_to` or query? `belongs_to :user` should be in `Pdform` model. And the query - just where you need it. As I see in the question, you want to execute it in `pdforms_controller`.